# guardar cadena en un archivo binario con un tamaño en bytes especifico

Tags: c#

Buen día.
Estoy intentando guardar en un archivo binario información, pero necesito que ciertos datos tengan el mismo tamaño, en este caso 35 bytes, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = "diccionario.dd";
        FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(file);
        string n = "Arturo";

            char[] name = new char[35];
            name = n.ToCharArray();
    }
```

El problema es que necesito que se guarde con exactamente 35 bytes de largo , por eso intente crear un char[35] pensando que tomaría en cuenta los espacios vacios pero no es así, hay alguna manera de lograr esto? 
 Saludos.

Comment: Has probado a crear un `byte[35]` en lugar de un char? El char es una estructura de 16 bits, no de 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes conseguir lo que quieres, y de paso simplificar tu código, usando la sobrecarga apropiada de [ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.asciiencoding.getbytes?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_ASCIIEncoding_GetBytes_System_String_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Byte___System_Int32_):

```
var bytes = new byte[35];
var cadena = "Hola mundo";
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cadena, 0, cadena.Length, bytes, 0);
File.WriteAllBytes("diccionario.dd", bytes);
```

por supuesto cambiando la codificación ASCII por UTF8 u otra que necesites si es necesario.

A tener en cuenta: esto te tirará una excepción si la cadena no cabe en 35 bytes una vez codificada. Si necesitas comprobar por adelantado la longitud de la cadena en bytes, usa `Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(cadena)`.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono perfecto, cuando lo recupere del archivo para guardarlo en un string en mi proyecto seria igual? saludos

Comment: Para recuperar la cadena podrías hacer algo como `var bytes=File.ReadAllBytes(fichero)` y `var cadena=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length).TrimEnd('\0')`, si es que la codificación que usas no mete ceros en el resultado.